# Text bleeding outside element

Tags: html, css

Alright, so first off let me say, I'm really new to coding websites. In trying to Google my way around the problem has utterly failed in trying to fix it...haha. So I'm sorry if very similar questions like this have been asked before.

**Problem:** Contents of my news div bleed outside the element. I got SOMEWHAT closer to solving it by adding the overflow:hidden to the the parent div (wrap). That eliminated the bleed over top of my background image, but it's still bleeding off the element instead of scaling downwards.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<body>

<div id="wrap">

<div id="nav" >
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="recent" align="center">
<ul>
<li><img src="images/ex1.jpg" width="136" height="72" alt="Example1" /></li>
<li><img src="images/ex1.jpg" width="136" height="72" alt="Example2" /></li>
<li><img src="images/ex1.jpg" width="136" height="72" alt="Example3" /></li>
<li><img src="images/ex1.jpg" width="136" height="72" alt="Example4" /></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="spacer" >
<img src="images/recentproj.jpg" width="700" height="22" alt="Recent projects" />
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Mauris vel magna. Mauris risus nunc, tristique varius, gravida in, lacinia vel, elit. Nam ornare, felis non faucibus molestie, nulla augue adipiscing mauris, a nonummy diam ligula ut risus. Praesent varius. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

<p>Nulla a lacus. Nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar lobortis purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec semper ipsum et urna. Ut consequat neque vitae felis. Suspendisse dapibus, magna quis pulvinar laoreet, dolor neque lacinia arcu, et luctus mi erat vestibulum sem. Mauris faucibus iaculis lacus. Aliquam nec ante in quam sollicitudin congue. Quisque congue egestas elit. Quisque viverra. Donec feugiat elementum est. Etiam vel lorem.</p>

<p>Aenean tempor. Mauris tortor quam, elementum eu, convallis a, semper quis, purus. Cras at tortor in purus tincidunt tristique. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut eu lectus eu metus molestie iaculis. In ornare. Donec at enim vel erat tempor congue. Nullam varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat hendrerit risus. Integer enim velit, gravida id, sollicitudin at, consequat sit amet, leo. Fusce imperdiet condimentum velit. Phasellus nonummy interdum est. Pellentesque quam.    </p>
</div>

<div id="news">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Newssssssss!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">HUGE ANNOUNCEMENT COMING UP RANODMLY BLAH BLAH BLAH</a></li>
<li><a href="#">WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Raaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaandom</a></li>
<li><a href="#">OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>

</div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
background: #FFFFFF url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

#wrap {
width:785px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}


#nav {
width: 768px;
height: 40px;
margin: 40px auto;
background: #fff;

}

#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:6px;
}

#nav li {
display:inline;
padding:28px;
}

    a:link,a:visited {
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#1f8fbc;
        text-align:center;
        padding:6px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        }

    a:hover,a:active {
        background-color:#26acdb;
        color: #FFF;
}

#recent {
margin: 255px auto 5px;

}
#recent ul li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 25px;
}

#spacer {
width: 700px;
height: 22px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0;
}

#content {
float: left;
width: 470px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
background: #FFF;
}

#news {
float: right;
width: 310px;
padding-right: 5px;
margin: 0;
background: #FFF;

}
```

Any sort of help solving that would be amazing....plus if pretty much everything I did is done stupidly, PLEASE tell me. haha

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept a helpful answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, it's the long text within the #news div that's not wrapping.

Try adding this to your #news CSS: word-wrap: break-word;